# radio buttons tkinter passing host value

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying use radio buttons to select which host I'm referring to since ultimately there will
only be two and they are fixed addresses.

This is the error:
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Untitled 2.py", line 63, in 
    command=lambda: callback_power_off(off, host))
  File "Untitled 2.py", line 28, in callback_power_off
    connection.connect((host, port))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found

```
from Tkinter import *
from socket import *
port = 7142

on = '02 00 00 00 00'
off = '02 01 00 00 00'




def callback_power_on(data, host):
    if not host:
        print "No host given!"
        return
    print "power on!"
    connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    connection.connect((host, port))
    connection.sendall(add_checksum(data))
    connection.close()


def callback_power_off(data, host):
    if not host:
        print "No host given!"
        return
    print "power off!"
    connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    connection.connect((host, port))
    connection.sendall(add_checksum(data))
    connection.close()


def add_checksum(s):
    result = []
    acc = 0
    for hexcode in s.split():
        code = int(hexcode, 16)
        acc += code
        result.append(chr(code))
    result.append(chr(acc))
    return ''.join(result)

master = Tk()
host = StringVar()
Radiobutton(master, text="Silas", variable = host, value ="172.25.13.10").pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(master, text="Beatrice", variable = host, value ="172.25.13.12").pack(anchor=W)

#entered_host = StringVar()
#e = Entry(master, textvariable=entered_host)
#e.pack()

b = Button(
    master,
    text="Power On",
    command=lambda: callback_power_on(on, host))
    #command=lambda: callback_power_on(on, host)

b.pack()

c = Button(
    master,
    text="Power Off",
    command=lambda: callback_power_off(off, host))
    #command=lambda: callback_power_on(on, host)
c.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that `connect` needs a string but you are passing in the `StringVar` instance. Use the `StringVar` method `get()` to retrieve the string value.

Here's a slight variation on your example, notice the use of `entered_host.get()` in the button command functions:

```
from Tkinter import *
from socket import *
port = 7142

on = '02 00 00 00 00'
off = '02 01 00 00 00'


def callback_power_on(data, host):
    if not host:
        print "No host given!"
        return
    print "power on!"
    connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    connection.connect((host, port))
    connection.sendall(add_checksum(data))
    connection.close()


def callback_power_off(data, host):
    if not host:
        print "No host given!"
        return
    print "power off!"
    connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    connection.connect((host, port))
    connection.sendall(add_checksum(data))
    connection.close()


def add_checksum(s):
    result = []
    acc = 0
    for hexcode in s.split():
        code = int(hexcode, 16)
        acc += code
        result.append(chr(code))
    result.append(chr(acc))
    return ''.join(result)

master = Tk()

entered_host = StringVar()
e = Entry(master, textvariable=entered_host)
e.pack()

b = Button(
    master,
    text="Power On",
    command=lambda: callback_power_on(on, entered_host.get()))
b.pack()

c = Button(
    master,
    text="Power Off",
    command=lambda: callback_power_off(off, entered_host.get()))
c.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Does the .get() method always need to be part of my callback argument?

Comment: Not really, you just need to make sure to use a string like `callback_power_on(on, '127.0.0.1')`. Alternatively, you could change your functions to accept a StringVar instance and do the conversion inside the function.